# Solve the following recurrences using backward substitutions:

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the following recurrences using backward substitutions:
$x(n) = 3x(n-1)$, for $n > 1$; $x(1) = 4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Just start substituting:

$$\begin{align*}
x(n)&=3x(n-1)\\
&=3\big(3x(n-2)\big)\\
&=3^2x(n-2)\\
&=3^2\big(3x(n-3)\big)\\
&=3^3x(n-3)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and so on. In general, when you’ve worked back $k$ steps you’ll have $x(n)$ equal to some multiple of $x(n-k)$; what will that multiple be if the pattern holds up?

Now take $k=n-1$, and you’ll get a closed form for $x(n)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused.  Would the multiple be 3^k?

Comment: @zmart372: Yes, it would. Each time you step back, you multiply by $3$, so when you’ve stepped back $k$ times (to reach $x(n-k)$), you’ve multiplied by $3$ $k$ times, or by $3^k$.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @zmart372: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

try showing by induction that $x_n = 4\times3^{n-1}$